# Er diagram / database management

Tags: database, entity-relationship

how can Show below details in er
*
YY Owns many equipment such as burners, tables, serving dishes, cups and etc. Under equipment type there can be many units. For each unit purchased date, price should be logged. Equipment is owned by a branch.

Answer (score 0):

1) create table product 
        (product_id number,
         product_name varchar2(300),
         type_product varchar2 (300))
2) create table branch 
        (branch_id number,
         branch_name varchar2(300)
3) create table price
        (product_id number,
         branch_id  number,
         price      number,
         quantity_product number )